# Custom error handler strange behaviour - PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, header, http-headers, custom-errors

I am having weird problems with custom error handler, here it is:

```
function errHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if($errno)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
        header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
        header('Retry-After: 3600');

        exit;
    }

    return true;
}
```

everytime when running:

```
set_error_handler('errHandler');
```

The header is being sent despite lack of any error? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `var_dump()` `$errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline` to see if that gives any hint.

Comment: the thing is that nothing is being passed but for some reason headers are being run - only headers - exit before them not stoping it to being sent

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior on my system (5.3.5/Linux). It works as expected.

Comment: ok, as it turns out there were a static call to a non static function which hasn't been reported by PHP internal errors, only by custom one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is "503 Service Unavailable"

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: thanks, but that is not a problem here, the header shouldn't been triggered if no errors provided.